# If statement in onClick method does not get executed

Tags: android, if-statement, onclicklistener

I have two views, in this case `circleView1` and `circleView2`. You have to touch them both at the same time so they move to a random position on the screen.

This is what my `onClickListener` looks like:

```
View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (circleView1.isPressed() && circleView2.isPressed()) {
                            setCirclesRandomPosition(circleView1, circleView2);
                            counter++;
                            scoreGM2.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                            startGame2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }


                        if (circleView1.isPressed() && circleView2.isPressed() && counter == 1) {
                            timer.start();
                        }
                    }
        };

        circleView1.setOnClickListener(ocl);
        circleView2.setOnClickListener(ocl);
```

The following code gets executed

```
if (circleView1.isPressed() && circleView2.isPressed() && counter == 1) {timer.start();}
```

But this doesn't

```
if (circleView1.isPressed() && circleView2.isPressed()) {
                            setCirclesRandomPosition(circleView1, circleView2);
                            counter++;
                            scoreGM2.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                            startGame2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
```

The "same" code from another class works with just one view and looks like this:

```
neoncircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               setCircleRandomPosition(neoncircle);
               counter++;
               scoreGM1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
               startGame1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

               if (counter == 1) {
                   timer.start();
               }
           }
       });
```

The `onClickListener` for `circleView1` and `circleView2` looks different than for one view because this was the only way I figured out how to make it work for two simultaneous clicks.

*I didn't post the whole code because it's really long. But if you need the whole code I'll post it.*

**EDIT**

I tried out **@matdev**'s suggestion but now nothing happens when I touch both Views. They just stay there.

Here's the code

```
View.OnTouchListener otl = new View.OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

             if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {

                 int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

                 if (pointerCount == 2) {

                         setCirclesRandomPosition(circleView1, circleView2);
                         counter++;
                         scoreGM2.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                         startGame2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         timer.start();
                 }

             }

             return true;
         }

     };

     circleView1.setOnTouchListener(otl);
     circleView2.setOnTouchListener(otl);
```

Comment: "You have to touch them both at the same time" - your code does not use onTouch, but onClick.. intentional?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, because it's easier with onClick.

Comment: I think `if (circleView1.isPressed() && circleView2.isPressed())` don't get executed because your ontouch on the second view is not exacly at the same time as on your first view. You can try to add a delay of some milliseconds like 50 or something before this if section. Then it should work...

Comment: @Cagri Ersoz I have updated my answer to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of OnClickListener, you should use OnTouchListener to track multiple touch.

Here is a code sample to get you started:

```
View.OnTouchListener otl = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

            switch (maskedAction) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {

                    counter++;
                    if (counter == 2) {

                        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onTouch() pointerCount = 2 !");
                        // Your code ...
                        //setCirclesRandomPosition(circleView1, circleView2);
                        //scoreGM2.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                        //startGame2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    counter--;
                    break;
                }
            }

        return true;
    }
};

circleView1.setOnTouchListener(otl);
circleView2.setOnTouchListener(otl);
```

For more infos on handling multiple touch on Android:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html

Comment: This might be useful for me if I could understand it....I get what you're trying to explain me but I have no idea how to practically do this. I don't know how to write the code for that. I tryied it for over 2 hours now, searhcing SO, google, trying it out by myself, nothing works.

Comment: It not very different from your code, it's using OnTouchListener instead of OnClickListener. I've updated my answer with more details. Try it out and tell us the issue you are facing so we can help you out.

Comment: I edited my question and posted the code I tried out.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method the same way as you did before.
Rather then checking for two click listener it would be better to have if inside the click listener.

```
neoncircle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               setCircleRandomPosition(neoncircle);
               counter++;
               scoreGM1.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
               startGame1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

               if (counter == 1) {
                   timer.start();
               }
           }
       });
```